# Sitecore List Manager default Email related rules not working

Tags: xconnect, paas, list-manager

Sitecore version: 9.1 Update 1 on Azure PAAS

We are trying to create a segmented list based on OOTB rule **where the contact clicked any email** but after selecting this rule in rule editor window while saving the segment, getting this error.
[image]

In the network tab and logs, we can see this request is failing:
https://domainname.com/sitecore/shell/default.aspx?xmlcontrol=Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.SegmentBuilder&hdl=F9B6F685C13F4C5E8FB703A6F5E64748

> [XdbSearchUnavailableException: The HTTP response was not successful: InternalServerError]
> Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory) +653 Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory) +61
> Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.GetBatchEnumeratorSync(IAsyncQueryable`1 asyncQueryable, Int32 defaultBatchSize) +195 Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.&lt;&gt;c.&lt;CountContacts&gt;b__24_0(IAsyncQueryable`1 contacts) +22
> Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.SegmentationEngine.PerformSearch(IContactSearchQueryFactory queryFactory, Func`2 searchWork, Byte[] syncToken, ContactExpandOptions expandOptions) +317
> Sitecore.XConnect.Segmentation.SegmentationEngine.CountContacts(IContactSearchQueryFactory queryFactory) +202
> Sitecore.Shell.Applications.Analytics.SegmentBuilder.SegmentBuilderForm.EditFilterCondition(ClientPipelineArgs args) +1250
>
> [TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
> System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +132
> System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +146
> Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
> Sitecore.Nexus.Pipelines.NexusPipelineApi.Resume(PipelineArgs args, Pipeline pipeline) +274
> Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.ResumePipeline() +215
> Sitecore.Web.UI.Sheer.ClientPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +806
> System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
> System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479

Couple of things we have looked into already:

1. Email sent/open/click are being tracked correctly in EXM dashboard.
2. Other OOTB list manager rules except Email are working fine.
3. On all app service in Azure, the Xconnet client certificate is pointing to correct value.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Got this response from Sitecore Support:**

The reported issue is the result of the following error on `xConnect CollectionSearch` instance:

```
[Error] Sitecore.XConnect.Operations.XdbSearchOperation`1[Sitecore.XConnect.Contact]: System.NotSupportedException: Contact.Interactions is not currently supported in Azure
at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Queries.QueryNodeMapper`1.TryVisitInteractionsJoinNode(AnyNode node)
at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Queries.QueryNodeMapper`1.Visit(AnyNode node, QueryNodeMapperArguments argument)
at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Queries.QueryNodeMapper`1.Visit(AndNode node, QueryNodeMapperArguments argument)
at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.Queries.QueryNodeMapper`1.ToTextQuery(PredicateNode predicate)
at Sitecore.Xdb.Collection.Search.Azure.AzureReader.<GetSearchResults>d__16`1.MoveNext()
```

The point is that `contact.Interactions.Any()` expression is not supported by Azure Search. The following limitation is specific to the Azure Search provider for xConnect search.

There were conversations with Microsoft about this in the past and at that moment they had no plans to add support for it.
Nevertheless, a feature request (reference number 229424) has been created for the product team so that we might come up with some alternative around the existing functionality in our future implementation.